# How to record sound from microphone in android app using meteor js

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor

i am new in meteor js. i want to  create a simple  android app in that want to record voice or sound from microphone. I have checked around and people had luck with `cordova-plugin-media-capture` however, it seems to record audio and archive it on the android device. i look on [this link](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-media-capture/index.html) but i don't know how to save recorded audio on device .if someone know this please help me and if knows other better package advice me.

Answer (score 1):

If your new to meteor learn and try meteor sample apps and then step by step to create a android application.

1. Create a simple app with button record audio
2. Button click to run function with `Meteor.isCordova`  inside put your cordova function [Cordova Audio Vedio Capture Function](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-media-capture/index.html).
3. Then try to build android application using meteor ,please try to this tutorial [Meteor run android](https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html).

Any Doubts comments or tweet [twitter.com/aboopallikara](https://twitter.com/aboopallikara)

Comment: yes.I created simple app using meteor run android and also used cordova audio capture function but on button click this function open audio recorder app  which installed in my device .

Comment: i want my own application and also want save that recorded voice